# SQL MDX Query: range of dates

Tags: sql, range, mdx, olap, cube

I have a Cube with a dimension date and I want to query this:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[MyMeasure] AS(
SUM((
    [Measures].[Count],
      [DimensionState].[Active],
    [CreatedDate].&[2008-03-28T00:00:00]
    :
    STRTOMEMBER( "[CreatedDate].&[" + [Date].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER.Lag(15).MemberValue + "]" )
)))

Select
    [Date].[Date].ALLMEMBERS on rows,
    [Measures].[MyMeasure] on columns

From [cube]
```

The problem is that it doesn't exists all the values for [DimensionDate]. So when I query for a no existent date, it give me an error.

Do you know how I could query a range when I don't have the borders of the range in the dimension?

Thanks!

Comment: If you can manage the Date Dimension, is a good practice to have complete date dimensions without missing dates.

Comment: Hi Michele, thank you very much for your answer. I can not manage the loading of the cube. I have the [Date].[Date].xxx complete, but not the other dates. Thanks!

Comment: and why can't you use directly [date].[date] for your range?

Comment: Hi Michele. I updated the query with another example. In that case I wanted to know how many items were active and older than 15 days for each [Date].[Date].xxx Thanks a lot!